# Parsing json Objects From Text File With Much Other Stuff - Python

Tags: python, json

I have an `html` page.

I read with `requests` and parsed a script tag with `beautifulsoup`, now this tag has loads of text, and some of it is *json* objects.

How can I read all the *json* objects from this text?

What I want to achieve is to get the products with prices from amazon daily deals and this is what I wrote for now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests

def FindRightScriptTag(soup):
    for tag in soup.find_all('script', type="text/javascript"):
        if 'sortedDealIDs' and 'dealDetails' in tag.text:
            return tag

url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/deals/"
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
tag = FindRightScriptTag(soup)
print (tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be good if you shared some of your code. In general if you know how to navigate down your beautiful soup xml tree you can pass the string you know to be json into the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

json.loads() is what you are looking for as it takes a json string to turn it into a Python object dict for you to use.

Comment: added to the main post